# Break multiple numbers in array into digits and count the repeating numbers

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to solve some basic java question:

i have an array like `int[] x = { 12, 24, 33 };.` I need to break it into digits like `{1, 2, 2, 4, 3 ,3}` and then count the repeating numbers this way: `1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:1.`

Until now i got this code but i can't save the digits into array.
Can some one help me ?

```
public class targil_2_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] x = { 12, 24, 33 };
        int[] ara = new int[x.length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {  
                ara[j] = x[i] % 10;
                x[i] = x[i] / 10;
                System.out.println(ara[j]);
            }
        }            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Use `ArrayList` class instead of `int[]`. It'll be easier to add objects in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have only 10 decimal digits from 0 to 9 , [0..9]

so we make an array with length 10 , like count :

```
int count[] = new int[10];
for(int i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
     if( x[i] == 0 ){
         count[0]++;
         continue;
     }
     while(x[i]!=0){
         int index = x[i] % 10;
         count[index]++;
         x[i] /= 10;
     }
}
```

then we will have the number of digits in count array , so we can print it :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    System.out.println(i+" : "+count[i]);
```

if your data is so big it is better to use Map
there are many ways to do this

Comment: Tnx, very good and easy done. i would add to the last part this line of code              for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
                
                if(count[i]!=0)
                System.out.println(i+" : "+count[i]);  In order to exclude not relevant numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to store individual digits, you need to store just count for digits. Lets assume, that you're working with 10 based numbers, then code can looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = { 12, 24, 33, 0, 10, 555 };

    int[] count = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        int num  = x[i];
        if (num == 0) {
            count[0]++;
            continue;
        }

        while (num > 0) {
            count[num % 10]++;
            num = num / 10;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
}
```

Output is

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Use {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 12, 24, 33 };
        Map<Integer, Long> result = Arrays.stream(x).boxed()
                                        .map(String::valueOf)
                                        .collect(joining())
                                        .chars().boxed()
                                        .collect(groupingBy(Character::getNumericValue, counting()));
        System.out.println(result); //prints {1=1, 2=2, 3=2, 4=1}
    }
}
```

## Explanation

1. First line convert an `int[]` to a `Stream<Integer>` **(for each element)**
2. Convert `Stream<Integer>` to `Stream<String>`
3. Reduce the `Stream<String>` to `String`
4. Create a `Stream<Integer>` **(for each digit)**
5. Count the occurences of each digit in a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Digits are 0-9. Build a counter array of size 10, and count each digit extracted in the proper index of the counter array ("counter[digit]++").

Edit: Of- course, in the end you can build the desired result array based on the counter array.

For example: result[0] = "0:" + counter[0];"

Good Luck!